# In a string performing wave motion

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

In a string after the wave is generated, oscillation energy is transferred in the pulse due to workdone by tension.
Now,for an electron being a wave what force transfers it's oscillation energy?

Answer (score 1):

Your question assumes that the wave function associated with an electron represents the distributed mass of the electron. There is no such assumption in quantum theory. The wave is simply a mathematical function that models the probability of the electron manifesting as a particle in a particular volume of space. The wave function is not the oscillation of an object with mass, so it does not have an energy of vibration as a string might.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to Marco's answer, the electron wave functions are the solutions of the Schrodinger equation. Let's say this electron is localized in a potential well, the boundary conditions that we apply affect which solutions that are possible here and give rise to the standing wave-like solutions. As Marco explained, this does not arise because of the electron wave reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the wave or the pulse in the string is **mechanical in nature**. Such waves **require medium** to propagate. In your case, the string itself is medium. Other examples are waves in water with water as medium, sound waves with air as medium and so on. At elementary level, these (mechanical waves) **arises due to attractive and repulsive forces** of electrons.

But the kind of waves that are associated with photons, electrons and protons **are not mechanical**, they **don't require any medium**. So they don't arise due to any force but it's by nature that they move this way. Also, when electron moves, it's **not like they are moving continuously through the space**. In fact, their position can't be known with certainty but given by probability. So there is **no transfer of energy**.
In other words, **there is transfer of energy between different particles in a mechanical wave** (string wave for example). The **particles themselves are not moving** from one place to other. But in case of electrons, there is **no transfer of energy between particles, because the electron is the only particle**. Also, the **electron itself is moving** with the wave.

*Hope this answer help atleast so a little, we all know quantum behaviors are not intuitive.*